# What are "single account SMTP plugins" in "Exceptions to verification requirements" of Google OAuth API verification?

Tags: smtp, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api, smtp-auth

Does anyone know what are the "single account SMTP plugins" referenced here in this [Google OAuth API policy](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#zippy=%2Cexceptions-to-verification-requirements)?

See the last bullet of the "Exceptions to verification requirements":

> SMTP/IMAP/WP: The app is used to send emails through WordPress, or similar single-account SMTP plugins.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

**Single-account** is one account connected to your project or the only sender in it and **SMTP plugins** refers to the plugin that uses this OAuth token in order to send messages.

In summary, the bullet **SMTP/IMAP/WP** means that if you are using WordPress and set it up to be able to send emails using Gmail scopes, this is relegated to a single account SMTP plugin use and is not applicable for verification. Otherwise if your app is meant for public use it might require using https://mail.google.com/ scope, you will need to submit your app for the restricted scope verification.